# Better way to run Python continiously or limit CPU usage

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I´m running a raspberry pi4 as an attendance tool.
The Pi itself is bored with the Tasks running on it which is basically a nodejs Server a Web Frontend aswell as a Postgres DB.

However if I start my Python Script to check constantly for RFID Tags the CPU rises to 30% usage with one core maxed out which leads to a Temperature increase.

Since all other tasks are basically a no brainer for the PI I was wondering if there is any way to throttle this process down or a better approach for the python script.

The script itself is absolutely basic but unfortunately needs to run in an endless loop like:

```
reader = SimpleMFRC522()
while true:
        id, text = reader.read()
        if(id):
              ...processData
```

I´m aware that 30% CPU usage is also pretty much nothing but since the PI does not have any FANs or Heatsinks on it I´m a little concerned about the Temperature in productive env.

Also, since this task does basically nothing but check for rfid tags and if found post data to a restapi, I´m feeling like it´s a waste on used performance overall.

Thanks!

Comment: well, why does `reader.read()` return if there's no work to be done? Or maybe you don't know that you can block on file descriptors becoming ready (`epoll`/`poll`/`select`)?

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for your answer! I´ve edited my above post on which reader is - it is a Simple Libary to read out the NFC Scanner. However I´m quite unsure about your answer unfortunately I´m not that familiar with python - could you point this out by a bit maybe?

Comment: Add a short `time.sleep()`, maybe 0.1 s.

Comment: @KlausD. nope, that's an anti-pattern. The wrapper used explicitly uses non-blocking reads, where Midoxx actually needs blocking-until-ready interfacing. The solution is not to sleep (which might lead to missed observations!) but using the blocking interface instead of the non-blocking one.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the library, it looks like it's a non-blocking read:
https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python/blob/52d5a6952c70c97a834593fc8092fa9d40c87a2e/mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py#L16

Answer (score 0):

You want your `read` call to block; sadly, the [very... thin "simple" wrapper you're using](https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python/blob/master/mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py) **explicitly** does a non-blocking read. So, simply replace `SimpleMFRC522` with an `MFRC522` object and read blockingly.

Comment: May I ask you to add a little code Snippet? I´m quite unsure what you mean in detail and how this prevents the script from running in an endless loop. Would be highly appreciated!

Comment: sorry, no. I'm not in a situation to deliver code examples right now. The trick really is to avoid using the "no_block" variants of funcitons in your endless loop. The loop itself is fine.